# ODAC 18c Release 1 (18.3.0.0.0) Installer crashing

Tags: oracle, odac, odt

I am trying to install `ODAC 18c Release 1 (18.3.0.0.0)` and when I click on the `Setup.exe` it shows the black screen(command prompt ) and there after nothing is coming. The universal Installer is not at all loading.

Currently I am using `Windows 10 Enterprise edition` ,

```
VS 2015 , 2017 Professional editions are installed. 
My Machine is 64 bit
```

Other than the above I have installed `ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit` also in my system.

No idea why the installer is crashing.

I could see a prerequisite like

```
Access to an Oracle Database Server (Oracle 11g Release 2 or later)
```

is needed for the instillation in installation guide. In fact my oracle database server is located in some other place and we are accessing that from my location , so I need only client for accessing that. I am not sure what they meant by

```
Access to an Oracle Database Server (Oracle 11g Release 2 or later)
```

Do I need to install the Oracle database 11g+ ?? Do the crashing issue is because of some other reasons ?
Can someone help me to resolve this ?

Methods I have tried so far :

Open the install folder directly and click on the oui.exe directly

Disconnect internet and try to install

Run the installation exe in elevated rights mode

Kill the java.exe from task manager and try to install

None of the above methods are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I found the reason.

I didn't have a _JAVA_OPTIONS in the system variables. I have added that and run the installer as run as administrator. 
The variable value should be `-Xmx512M`

[image]